# should i use memcache with a noSQL database?

Tags: cassandra, memcached, nosql

In an architecture where i have a cache between the MySQL database and the application.  i am having the issue of data consistency, as my cache is for a longer time than 20 minutes, as it is a very high load server.

My question is if I use a noSql database, is it necessary to still have a cache server? The idea is a memcache between the application layer and database layer.

Thinking of an alternative to my current architecture.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Consistency is missing in mysql?(that's weird ) Are you maintaining data across network partition ? Memcached and cassandra are completely different utilities.

Comment: That depends solely on what NoSQL database you are using. Some like MongoDB have their build-in memory cache, so putting an additional memcached in front of it is quite redundant.

Answer (score 6):

Memcached is less important to Cassandra now than was the case a few years ago. The Cassandra read latencies have improved a lot and SSDs help out as well. It mostly depends on your latency demands. Here's an interesting link from Netflix on how they were able to remove their caching layer from an example cluster and get the same performance with SSD based nodes in AWS: [Netflix TechBlog](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/benchmarking-high-performance-io-with.html)

The short version is they were able to get an 80 node Cassandra + cache cluster down to 15 nodes by switching to SSD based EC2 nodes.

I would start with an SSD based Cassandra cluster and add the caching layer if it is needed for extremely low latency reads.

Comment: That article did not include the network cost across AZs

Answer (score 0):

We use Cassandra for heavy read/write load with no caching at all. Something one usually can't think of doing with a relational database. Well, even Solr `/get` handler or ElasticSearch's retrieve document should not require anything in the middle. Of course it depends on your loads, but generally, whereas caching is a requirement to accommodate relational backends it may not be the case with noSQL.

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to consisitncy in the database layer, Cassandra will not give you the consistency you desire since it provides [eventual consistency](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_transactions_c.html) only. Cassandra will provide you fast writes, but no guarantee of that data being distributed consistently across the cluster. Yes, it may guarantee the write to another node's commit log if you have the `ALL` consistency flag set. But that only means the data is replicated safely, since that data gets will be **eventually** written to the database.

@stinkymatt is right, you can even add SSD if money is not an option to speed up process of persisting the data across the cluster.

Comment: The down vote wasn't me, but it might have been because some of the details in your answer are incorrect. The ANY consistency level is actually the lowest consistency level. Ronino's question about consistency has to do with inconsistency introduced by the need for a caching layer. If immediate consistency is required at the DB level, Cassandra can support that with quorum reads and writes. The consistency level can be set per-operation. Cassandra also now supports serializable consistency with compare-and-set operations enabled by paxos.